# Full Width Background Image Sizing

Tags: css, web, background-image

I am looking to fix my second full width image (the one in the middle of the page) so that is fits horizontally the same as the one above in the header image. Can somebody double check my CSS so see if it is correct. It needs to auto resize to fit the screen like the header image above. When i view it on mobile it is not fitting correctly. Thanks for taking a look.

http://www.jobspark.ca

```
.fullWidthSectionBG { 
background-image: url('http://static.squarespace.com/static/513d5347e4b0abff73be5264/t/519c45c4e4b084baf13d7e27/1369195972115/rocktruck2.jpg');
border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd; 
border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
margin-left: -1600px;
margin-right: -1600px;
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:330px;
overflow: hidden;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto; 
}
```

Comment: please see the answer to this question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16706285/2397883

Comment: Darn still no solution. Do you know how to accomplish this if it was just an image and not a background image

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the height on to your div I think. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku4bj/). I just added a height to the div and now it resizes fine... Is that what you needed it to do?

```
.fullWidthSectionBG { 
background-image: url('http://static.squarespace.com/static/513d5347e4b0abff73be5264/t/519c45c4e4b084baf13d7e27/1369195972115/rocktruck2.jpg');
width:100%;
background-position:center;
height:575px;
}
```

Updated css (still resizes)

```
.fullWidthSectionBG { 
background-image: url('http://static.squarespace.com/static/513d5347e4b0abff73be5264/t/519c45c4e4b084baf13d7e27/1369195972115/rocktruck2.jpg');
background-position: bottom center;
background-size: cover;
height:575px;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Didn`t quite work how I would like so not sure what else to try. I changed my css back to something a bit different

Comment: I did an inspect element on the top background image div as you said you wanted it like that so I've updated my answer.